# OpenSSL on Google Colab?

Tags: openssl, cryptography, certificate, rsa, google-colaboratory

I would like to know if there is a possibility to have the same use as OpenSSL on google colab ?
And if you have example...

The functions I'm looking for :

- Generate RSA key
- Encrypt/decrypt with public/private key
- Hash a message
- Sign files and verify it (ex: SHA256)
- Create certificate and use it

Everything for cryptography in a way.

Thank you for your help.

Sincerely,

Johan

Comment: Please do describe what you tried, where you got stuck, and any error messages you observed.

Comment: I tried to open the help with openssl help, not working.
I tried to generate a RSA key with "openssl genrsa –out bob.pem 2048", same.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I would like to make cryptography with gg Colab, first step is generate keys, on OpenSSL, it's "openssl genrsa –out bob.pem 2048", does it exists something similar on Colab ? Or not ?